# PayPal adapative payments - setting description?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Couple of issues I'm hoping the community can shed some light on here...

It seems impossible to customize the "Description" that appears in the payment review screen - It always shows the primary receiver's name.  I have used the SetPaymentOptions call and that does not do anything useful.

I have found that the embedded flow URL will show the details (sort of...you  have to expand the details), however the receiver's name(s) will be shown above each of the detailed items.  I guess this makes sense, but it would be nice on the non-embedded flow method to be able to customize this "Description"...anyone have any experience here?

Second is the fact that it seems you can't get the details (shipping address) even if you request that the you force the user to enter a shipping address.

I have not been able to find a way to retrieve the user's address after the payment has been authorized using adaptive payments.  Again anyone have experience here to say it can or can't be done?

Thanks all...

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think you can only set the item name? Via, SetPaymentOptions  - like so:

`receiverOptions.invoiceData.item(0).name=ITEM1 TITLE (or desc)`

That being said - I'm not having a huge amount of luck getting the `SetPaymentOptions` function to work for me (no errors, but it just doesn't seem to apply the changes I'm passing it)

**UPDATE** - I just came across this setting for `SetPaymentOptions` - hopefully that helps:

> ReceiverOptions - description - xs:string